# How to configure MS Edge to allow “insecure” downloads?

Tags: windows-10, security, microsoft-edge

I’m using Microsoft Edge.

Every time I download an article in PDF format, instead of the article I getting “can’t be downloaded securely” message. I have to click on the ellipsis button and click “keep”. Then I get one more warning with the same text, saying “can’t be downloaded securely”. I have to click one more button saying “keep anyway”, and only then I get my PDF downloaded.

How to get rid of the “security” to download files automatically, regardless on the transport protocol?

I’m not connected to AD. Using latest version of MS Edge, Version 102.0.1245.39 (Official build) (64-bit). I’m not using Edge to view PDF documents because I want them in Acrobat reader, and the browser was configured appropriately.

A simple way to reproduce, click the first PDF link in that page: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Fast+Sweeping+Method&ia=web Because duckduckgo search engine uses https and the target web server missouri.edu doesn’t, Edge freaks out with these security warnings. Screenshots below.

[image]
[image]

Running `msedge.exe` with `--disable-extensions` command-line option didn’t help, it’s not an extension.

Comment: You are going to need to [edit] your question and provide more information.  Are you connected to an Active Directory domain?  What version of Edge are you running?  Can you provide a screenshot of the exact message you receive?  Can you give us an example of an article when converted into a PDF that generates this message? I assume you are using Edge for the association for PDFs?

Comment: @Ramhound Good points, see the update

Comment: @Ramhound I understand the developers rationale for the warnings — a link from https page points to http document. However, as an end user I don’t want these warnings, I want the PDFs.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, but what do I put in the edit box in that setting? It seems that setting only applies to individual domains? How to apply that to the entire internets?

Comment: @Ramhound It’s not just a flag, it also has a text input, and a comment says “Treat given (insecure) origins as secure origins. Multiple origins can be supplied as a comma-separated list. Origins must have their protocol specified e.g. "http://example.com".” Without specifying any origins, the flag changes nothing.

Comment: It appears it's not possible to disable this warning.  The underline reason you are getting the warning, in the specific example you provided, is that a google search is secure and you are clicking on a HTTP link.  You could get around this by using Edge as the PDF view then saving the PDF from within Edge or just click "keep anyway"